# Hibernate não estão gerando tabelas no banco MySQL

Tags: hibernate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="PedidoPU">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/cursojavaee" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="oliveira" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"" value="create"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />

        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" 
            value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Essa apas a mais é erro na hora de colocar na pergunta? => `name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto""`

Comment: Estas aspas a mais desconsidere, eu corrigi, o problema continua, a aplicação sobe sem erros, mais não gera as tabelas